# WIX Setup doesn't build

Tags: wpf, deployment, wix

I am using the `WIX` binaries from a local folder instead of the common installation. So i had to overwrite my Paths like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <WixToolPath>$(TeamProjectBuildUtilsDir)Tools\WIX\</WixToolPath>
      <WixTargetsPath>$(WixToolPath)Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
      <WixTasksPath>$(WixToolPath)WixTasks.dll</WixTasksPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

It was working ok, but today i tried it again and get this:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException" in WixTasks.dll:
> Additional information: The file or assembly
> "file:///D:\Repos\MyProject\BuildUtils\Tools\WIX\candle.exe" or a
> dependency could not be found. To progress is not supported.
> (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

I am not very expirenced with `WIX` and don't know what to do. It worked fine.

My VS freezes after this build step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you downloaded the WiX binaries .zip, you need to "unblock" the file (remove the stream that indicates it was downloaded from the Internet). .NET won't load files that are marked as coming from the Internet.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try this in two days. Really looking forward to it.